# How to see original script or function from RData?

Tags: r, workspace

I created a very small script (without saving) in RCmdr top window, but I only saved the workspace.

When I reload this I can't see anything that was in the top window originally. My mistake I know, but is there a way to see any hint of the functions etc I may have called, from the workspace file? I can see the objects - but not what created them.

Comment: Check to see if there is a `.Rhistory` file where you saved the `.RData` file.

Comment: No .RHistory unfortunately

Comment: I question your understanding about your OS and how the file management occurs. In Windows and Macs, the `.Rhistory` file will be invisible unless you make special efforts.

Answer (score 1):

If you open a new R session, try hitting the up-arrow keys. The normally invisible .Rhistory file is usually loaded at the start of a new session if the prior session ended normally. If the session is open in a GUI hten you may be able to display the list of commands with a menu command. This may also display that file:

```
loadhistory(file = ".Rhistory")
```

The history is cumulative, so unless you had a really long session intervening you may still be able to get code going back for several session. I think it keeps the last 500 entries by default. Actually turns out to be 512. See:

```
?history
```